# How to drop duplicates in csv by pandas library in Python?

Tags: python, pandas

I've been looking around tried to get examples but can't get it work the way i want to.

I want to dedupe by 'OrderID' and extract duplicates to seperate CSV.
Main thing is I need to be able to change the column which I want to dedupe by, in this case its 'Order ID'.

Example Data set:

> ```
> ID    Fruit   Order ID    Quantity    Price
> 1     apple      1111        11       £2.00
> 2     banana     2222        22       £3.00
> 3     orange     3333        33       £5.00
> 4     mango      4444        44       £7.00
> 5     Kiwi       3333        55       £5.00
> ```

Output:

> ```
> ID    Fruit   Order ID    Quantity    Price
> 5     Kiwi       3333        55       £5.00
> ```

I've tried this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/shane/PycharmProjects/PythonTut/deduping/duplicate example.csv')

new_df = df[['ID','Fruit','Order ID','Quantity','Price']].drop_duplicates()

new_df.to_csv('C:/Users/shane/PycharmProjects/PythonTut/deduping/duplicate test.csv', index=False)
```

Issue i have is it doesn't remove any duplicates.

Comment: _All the examples code I have tried either return no data set or just return the exact same data set._ We can't do much with a description, can you share an actual [mcve]?  Also, please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.

Comment: Hi, the image before was an example data set nothing real

Comment: "Real" or not, it's the same idea. Can you share the data in a *convenient* format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by creating a new dataframe with value_counts(), merging and than filtering.

```
# value_counts returns a Series, to_frame() makes it into DataFrame
df_counts = df['OrderID'].value_counts().to_frame()
# rename the column
df_counts.columns = ['order_counts']

# merging original on column "OrderID" and the counts by it's index
df_merged = pd.merge(df, df_counts, left_on='OrderID', right_index=True)

# Then to get the ones which are duplicate is just the ones that count is higher than 1
df_filtered = df_merged[df_merged['order_counts']>1]

# if you want everything else that isn't a duplicate
df_not_duplicates = df_merged[df_merged['order_counts']==1]
```

**edit:** the **drop_duplicates()** keeps only unique values, but if it finds duplicates it **will remove all values but one**. Which one to keep you set it by the argument "keep" which can be 'first' or 'last'

**edit2:** From your comment you want to export the result to csv.
Remember, the way I did above I've separated in 2 DataFrames:

a) All items that had a duplicate removed (df_not_duplicates)

b) Only items that had a duplicate still duplicated (df_filtered)

```
# Type 1 saving all OrderIds that had duplicates but still with duplicates:
df_filtered.to_csv("path_to_my_csv//filename.csv", sep=",", encoding="utf-8")

# Type 2, all OrderIDs that had duplicate values, but only 1 line per OrderID
df_filtered.drop_duplicates(subset="OrderID", keep='last').to_csv("path_to_my_csv//filename.csv", sep=",", encoding="utf-8")
```

Comment: Hi, thank you, will this export the duplicates to a csv as well

Comment: you can export the new to a .csv, i'll edit the answer with an example

Comment: @shaneo, done. I believe you want the "Type 2" export.

Comment: by the way, the reason your `drop_duplicates()` wasn't working is because you didn't set the argument `subset` to the column you want. So it tried to find duplicates considering all columns.

Comment: Not sure why when i use "Order ID" i get a trace back error. When i change it to "ID" it works, but no dupes are exported just the headers.

Comment: You need to set it to the exact name of the column you want, case senstive. Is it "Order ID" or "OrderID" ? It's exporting empty because there are no duplicates at column "ID".

Comment: thank you so much is pulled the dupes to the csv file. The aim i wanted to achieve a function like deduplicate in excel, by deduping on what column you want. Hopefully i wasn't to confusing. Thank you

Comment: No problem. You'll see that soon enough pandas will be much easier and intuitive. Also making it easier to search what you need. cheers.

Answer (score 0):

The error is in second line of code (you should use pd.DataFrame), if you want to use drop_duplicates method.

```
df = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/shane/PycharmProjects/PythonTut/deduping/duplicateexample.csv')

# Create dataframe with duplicates
raw_data = {'ID': [1,2,3,4,5], 
            'Fruit': ['apple', 'Banana', 'Orange','Mango', 'Kiwi'], 
            'Order ID': [1111, 2222, 3333, 4444, 5555], 
        'Quantity': [11, 22, 33, 44, 55],
        'Price': [ 2, 3, 5, 7, 5]}

new_df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['ID','Fruit','Order ID','Quantity','Price']).drop_duplicates()

new_df.to_csv('C:/Users/shane/PycharmProjects/PythonTut/deduping/duplicate test.csv', index=False)
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi, thank you. Issue is, it returns the same data not the duplicate only. Drop method was error by me i see now. I've been trying to figure this out for a while and working with different example still new to the pandas and python.

Comment: @shaneo, I got the insight that you are new to python and pandas. Keep working on it. kudos!